# MAC/IP binding doesn't work

Tags: centos, ip, mac-address

I use Centos-7 server for assigning MAC/IP. But some times users get other IP addresses.

My `dhcpd.conf`

```
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 { range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.254;option domain-name "dhcp.local";option routers 192.168.1.1; option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255; max-lease-time 7200;option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;}

include "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/dhcp_clients.conf";

allow booting;
allow bootp;
option option-128 code 128 = string;
option option-129 code 129 = text;
next-server 192.168.10.1;
filename "pxelinux.0";
```

In `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/dhcp_clients.conf` I have

`host User.userlaptop {hardware ethernet 00:11:22:33:44:55;fixed-address 192.168.1.34;}`

What is happening here? Why it misbehaves?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you verified which MAC address the user had when he tried to get an IP address? Some users like to use MAC-changers...

Comment: @dirkt yes. its not an issue here. it happens without any software tools.

Comment: Next step is to reproduce it, while listening with `wireshark` or `dhcpdump`. `dhcping` may also help. "Sometimes", "without any software tools" is a bit vague.